# Wrong update while cascading many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping

I have a many-to-many relationship defined on hibernate like this:

*User*

```
public class User{

private List<UserCustomer> userCustomerList;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<UserCustomer> getUserCustomerList() {
        return userCustomerList;
    }
}
```

*UserCustomer*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RTDB_USER_CUSTOMER")
@Component("userCustomerEntity")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.user", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.customer", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CUSTOMER")) })

public class UserCustomer {

    @EmbeddedId
    public UserCustomerId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ROLE_CUSTOMER", referencedColumnName = "ID") })           public RoleCustomer getRoleCustomer() {
        return roleCustomer;
    }

}
```

So a user has a list of UserCustomer, that represent roles of users over customers. The problem is, that when we change a role over a customer and call `update()`, instead of one row updated we get all the rows updated with the same role. When we call `merge()` it starts to perform a lots of queries and then gives `stackoverflow` exception ¿Could this be a mapping problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you have an entity for the join table (USER_CUSTOMER) ? It is not traditional in JPA to do so

Comment: Yes, it is because the join table has additional attributes (roles). Is there any way of doing it without it?

Comment: ok i missed that, you got USERS, CUSTOMERS and USER_CUSTOMER which has user id, customer id and role ?

Comment: That's it! Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: did you see this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the tables and updation code?

I think you are updating the role directly from `UserCustomer` which should be updating all the roles, as far as my understanding goes you do not want to update `UserCustomer` but only `RoleCustomer`. Try to fetch `RoleCustomer` and update it not the `UserCustomer`.