# Optimizing Spring-data / Hibernate ManyToMany Inserts

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, optimization, query-optimization

I'm a bit confused about the way Hibernate handles inserts into the JoinTable.

I need some extra fields in the JoinTable, so I chose the pretty common way, to create an `@Entity` for the JoinTable and use `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. And because the relations should be unique I created an `@EmbeddedId` within the JoinTable-Entity.

Lets call the classes `A`, `B` and `AB`:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<AB> abs;        
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<AB> abs;        
}

@Entity
public class AB implements Serializable {
    @Embeddable
    public static class Id implements Serializable {
        UUID aId;
        UUID bId;

        public Id(UUID aId, UUID bId) {
            this.aId = aId;
            this.bId = bId;
        }
    }

    public AB(A a, B b) {
        this.id.aId = a.getId();
        this.id.bId = b.getId();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;      

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private A a;

    @MapsId("bId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private B b;        
}
```

My commons case is, that I want to insert multiple new entries in to the JoinTable. So I have ONE `A_id` and multiple `B_ids`. In plain SQL, I'd simply do ONE query to get it all done. If the relation did already exist, the database will throw an error.

With hibernate I need to:

1. `SELECT`: give me an instance of class `A` for id = `A_id`
2. `SELECT`: give me an instance of class `B` for id = `B_id1` or id = `B_id2` or ...
3. Create a new instance of class `AB` and set the composite primary key and save `AB`

The last step produces (for each `AB`):

1. select * from AB where a_id = ... and b_id = ...
2. insert into AB (aId, bId) values (..., ...)

Here's my code. Using spring data jpa (`JpaRepository`):

```
A a = aRepo.findOne(aId);
List<B> bs = bRepo.findAll(bIdList);
for(B b : bs) {
    AB ab = new AB(a, b);
    abRepo.save(ab);
}
groupUserRepo.flush();
```

It doesn't matter if I just create a new ArrayList with the AB objects and afterwards save all of them at once or if I do it like in the code above. It always does a select and an insert for each object.

Is there a way to do it with less queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns has some useful information.

Comment: There's nothing about those additional queries that Hibernate has to do

Answer (score 0):

This is wierd as what you are seeing is the behavior of `saveOrUpdate` for a detached object.
I would expect hibernate to issue select for `A` and for `B` if they were detached object but not for `AB` as you are calling `save`.

Can you try with `persist` to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is: I'm using spring-data-jpa, which doesn't provide methods like persist or merge. It has only `save` and `saveAndFlush`.

Comment: Try implementing Persistable. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites