# Hibernate many to many mapping, join table with PK and extra columns

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

I've done the necessary changes to my models outlined [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/). However, I don't know what to put on my join table entity.

Note that my join table has a surrogate key , and two extra columns (date and varchar).

What I've got so far is:

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "tbl_bo_gui_user")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String ntName;
    private String email; 
    private Set<GroupUser> groupUsers = new HashSet<GroupUser>(0);

    // Constructors and some getters setters omitted

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<GroupUser> getGroupUsers() {
        return groupUsers;
    }

    public void setGroupUsers(Set<GroupUser> groupUsers) {
        this.groupUsers = groupUsers;
    }
}
```

Group.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "tbl_bo_gui_group")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Group implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String groupName;
    private String groupDesc;
    private Set<GroupUser> groupUsers = new HashSet<GroupUser>(0);

    // Constructors and some getters setters omitted

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.group", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<GroupUser> getGroupUsers() {
        return groupUsers;
    }

    public void setGroupUsers(Set<GroupUser> groupUsers) {
        this.groupUsers = groupUsers;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know what to put on my join table entity. Here it is.

GroupUser.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "tbl_bo_gui_group_user")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.group", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id")) })
public class GroupUser implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private User userId;
    private Group groupId;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private String createdBy;

    // constructors and getters and setters for each property

    // What now? ? No idea
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user to group would be a `Many-To-Many` relation. Now, you are splitting that up into Two `One-To-Many` Relations. Therefore your Mapping Entity simple needs to complete the `Many-To-Many` relation, by using `Many-To-One`:

```
public class GroupUser implements Serializable {
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User userId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Group groupId;
    private Date dateCreated;
    private String createdBy;
}
```

See also this example: [Mapping many-to-many association table with extra column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns) (The Answer with 38 upvotes)

Comment: How would I write the methods for saving the data of the users and groups in the model of the join table? There's `userService.setUser(user);` on the link that you gave but it didn't show a complete idea of an entity of a join table that I am looking for. I'm a hibernate newbie by the way.

Comment: @SciasTwentyThree If your entities are *set up properly* you dont need to care. I.e.: One User, 5 mappings, 5 Groups and each Group with 10 additional attributes: Call `userService.save(user)` and hibernate will persist all 61 entities ( 1 user + 5 mappings + 5 groups + 10 attribues per group (=50)) for you, because they are "connected".