# JPA : Additional fields in @JoinTable

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, ejb, one-to-many

I'm trying to create one-to-many relation with `@JoinTable`. Code works and does what it's supposed to do, BUT, is there a way to add more columns to the join-table? It will be a business application that needs some sort of history, so I will need fields like `add_user`, `update_user`, `timestamp` on create/update in the join-table. Is there an elegant way to do this with Java, without adding additional fields through altering tables? If there is, how to elegantly edit that data, lets say I add new relation, how to change value of mentioned fields? I say ***elegant***, because you can always do something ugly, in this case - create relation, then update fields of that relation by both IDs, I'm interested if there is prettier, kind of more Java, way.

Code of both entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {
    int id;
    String username;
    private List<Jobs> jobs;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="users_jobs_rel",
        joinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id") ,
        inverseJoinColumns= @JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="job_id") 
    )
    public List<Jobs> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }
    public void setJobs(List<Jobs> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
 }

@Entity
@Table(name="jobs")
public class Jobs {
    int id;
    String title;
    @ManyToOne
    private Users user;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "job_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, When you are using `Many-to-Many` , you need to create additional table for this relationship. But now, I do not have any idea why you are using one-to-many with creating new table (why? it is unnecessary). And the answer will be yes, you can join some additional columns to your table with `@JoinColumn` annotation. And pay attention if you really need bidirectional relationship :) Good luck

edited:

```
Is there an elegant way to do this with Java, without adding additional 
fields through altering tables?
```

What do you mean by saying 'altering'? Don't you let Hibernate to create it auto with using hbm2dll?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I already used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns to solve my problem. Still, +1 for effort :)