# @ManyToMany extra column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, modeling

I need to model a relationship between **clients** and **promotions**.
We need the history about clients promotions score **CLIENTS_PROMOTIONS_HISTORY** and the current score **CLIENTS_PROMOTIONS**

DB modelling is fine but I'm finding too hard to model the Entities.
I intend to use **CLIENTS_PROMOTIONS** table for relationship purposes only and so that the Clients can be aware of their promotions + current score on each promotion. But can't figure out where to store the current score.

Entities and Diagram:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
@SecondaryTable(name = "CLIENTS_PROMOTIONS",
                pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENT"))
class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CLIENT", nullable = false, unique = true)
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER", nullable = false, unique = true)
    User user;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    String name;

    @Column(name = "BIRTHDAY", nullable = false)
    Date birthday;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    String email;

    @Column(name = "SEX", nullable = false)
    Character sex;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "CLIENTS_PROMOTIONS", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENT"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROMOTION"))
    Set<Promotion> promotions;
}
```

-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROMOTIONS")
class Promotion {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PROMOTION", nullable = false, unique = true)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "ID_ESTABLISHMENT", nullable = false)
    Long establishmentId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false)
    String title;

    @Column(name = "LIMIT_SCORE", nullable = false)
    Long limitScore;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    String description;

    @Column(name = "REWARD", nullable = false)
    String reward;
}
```

[image: my eer diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an `Entity` for **Client_Promotions** and model `@ManyToOne` relationship of this `Entity` with the **Promotion** and **Client** entities, instead of a `@ManyToMany`.

Comment: @DaviArimateia unfortunatelly I think yes, because that is not a single join table... you have a field that needs an Entity to reflect its value.

Comment: I see =( it does make sense!

If any one need to implement this solution, here is my suggestion
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns