# Java SQL database class representation

Tags: java, sql, many-to-many, persistence

### **Tables:**

**Car**

- Long :: Car_id
- String :: Type

**Owner**

- Long :: Owner_id
- String :: name
- int :: age

**Car_Owner**

- Long :: Car_Id
- Long :: Owner_Id
- Date :: Bought_Date

### **Question:**

So i understand the best way to transfer data between java and a SQL DB is by using the java persistence API. Each table is represented as a java class with the @Entity annotation.

But how is the mid-table "Car_Owner" represented as a java class?

Comment: See here (many-to-many): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns

Answer (score 0):

the main idea is the relationship between both classes. check this [wiki-link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne) for more info about OneToOne relationship ( only if the business here is that a car has only one owner ).
if the business is that Owner has many cars , then check the ManyToOne [Link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne).

good luck with your assignment :)

Comment: thank you for the helpfull links, but i am currently struggling to understand ManyToMany relationship within JPA