# Add column to Join table?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, join

I am having some trouble adding a column to an existing join table. Below is how I want my join table to look like, but I am missing the `tenant_id` column in the join table in my actual implementation.

[image: Database Schema]

Below is my code for my JPA implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "label")
public class Label {
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenant_id;

    @Column(name = "label_id")
    private String label_id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Report.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"))
    private Set<Report> reports;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report {
    @Column(name = "tenant_id")
    private String tenant_id;

    @Column(name = "report_id")
    private String report_id;

    @column(name = "created_by")
    private String created_by;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Label.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "tagging", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "label_id"))
    private Set<Label> labels;

}
```

And the code basically puts the `id` of the `Report` class and `Label` class into the tagging table in place of the `report_id` and `label_id` columns respectively. The issue I'm having is that I want to add the `tenant_id` column to every existing entry in my `tagging` table. I tried

`ALTER TABLE tagging ADD COLUMN tenant_id varchar(255) NOT NULL;`

but because I have pre-existing data, I get an error saying that the `tenant_id` must have a default value. I want to somehow update every `tagging` table with the following:

`select tenant_id from report where report.id = tagging.report_id`, and perform this update the moment the values in my database are populated/created. Is there any way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I am confused slightly by your schema and your question however note that if you wish to record additional info about the relationship then you need to replace the '@ManyToMany' by creating an additional  entity pointing to "tagging" and give both Report and Label a '@OneToMany' relationship to this new Entity.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns

Comment: @AlanHay Thanks for letting me know. Are you saying that with any new rows I want to insert into tagging, I have to create an `Entity` called `tagging` and make a `@OneToMany` relationship with `report_id`, `label_id`, and `tenant_id`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, did I understand you problem properly. But if you need to add `tenant_id` and fill it you can do next.

First, add new column with default null:

```
ALTER TABLE tagging ADD COLUMN tenant_id varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Second, update all tenant_id:

```
UPDATE tagging t SET t.tenant_id = (SELECT r.tenant_id from report r WHERE r.id = t.report_id);
```

Third, modify `tagging` table constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tagging MODIFY COLUMN tenant_id varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

Note, that you must be sure, that your `report` table not containg `NULL` value in `tenant_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Just alter tagging (class)table as you mentioned above but add default value, that exists in your label table(class) and then update  tagging table(class) as you want to.