# JPA Order by column in many to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

My problem is a bit more complex than described from the first sight. Let me try to explain.
I have two entities with unidirectional ManyToMany relationship:

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ct_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "category_ct_id_seq", sequenceName = "category_ct_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "category_ct_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ct_name_key")
    private String nameKey;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_2_country",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c2c_category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c2c_country_id"))
    private Set<Country> countries;
}

public class Country {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "country_c_id_seq", sequenceName = "country_c_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "country_c_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "c_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "c_name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "c_iso_2_alpha")
    private String isoAlpha2Code;
```

And I'm retrieving the collection of Categories by an ISO code of country (actually, all categories, which has relation with the requested country). For this I've written a Specification:

```
public class CategorySpecification implements Specification<Category> {

    Country matchCountry;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Category> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        return builder.isMember(matchCountry, root.get("countries"));

    }
}
```

This works pretty fine. The problem is I need to have order priority for the Categories in every Country.
The transitive table looks like this:
[image]
So when I retrieve collection of Categories for the given Country, I want it to be ordered according to this `sort_order` column.

The corresponding SQL query looks so,thing like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM category
  JOIN category_2_country ON category.ct_id = category_2_country.c2c_category_id
WHERE c2c_country_id = ?
ORDER BY sort_order;
```

But how should I make it in my JPA entities? And how should I persist it back to the database, it this order needs to be changed dynamically (e.g. from the admin panel)?

EDITED:
Tables in database corresponding to the entities:

The one for Country
[image: Country]

And the One for Category:
[image]

EDITED 2:
I've managed to achieve the desired behaviour with a native query as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Category> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT ct.*\n" +
            "FROM category ct\n" +
            "  JOIN category_2_country c2c ON ct.ct_id = c2c.c2c_category_id\n" +
            "  JOIN country c ON c2c.c2c_country_id = c.c_id\n" +
            "WHERE c.c_iso_2_alpha = :countryIso\n" +
            "ORDER BY c2c.sort_order", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Category> findCategoriesForCountryOrdered(@Param("countryIso") String countryIso);
}
```

But still hope to have a more JPA/Hibernate way of doing this thing

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns) might be helpful.

Comment: I saw this thread before but still hope to have simpler solution than refactoring all the entities just because of the priority column

Answer (score 1):

As you using Specification you are using `JpaRepository` with  `JpaSpecificationExecutor`. `JpaSpecificationExecutor` api gives us a method     `findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort)`.

Using `Sort` class, you can specify by which property (and direction) you want to sort your result list.

Here is docs: [Sort](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html?is-external=true)

EDIT:
After some searches - unfortunately, without mapping association table into hibernate, you can't order by / sort by `sort_order` property. This is related to JPQL which can only works on mapped properties in entities - it can't reach tables in DB if you don't map them.

So, you can map your association table and create specification, which join that two tables and creates sorting by `sort_order`.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. But I can't pass to the Sort just the name of DB column. It has to be a property of either Category or a Country, but not a name of column in manytomany table. Might it be that I don't have any options rather than turn my ManyToMany table into a separate entity? :(

Comment: You have to pass a variables names from mapped entities. In you example that will be: `countries.sortOrder` assuming that `Country` class has `sortOrder` filed. Is it true?

Comment: It is not, unfortunately. sortOrder is specific not to a Country, but to Category-Country mapping.

Comment: Can you provide full `Country` and `Category` classes with mapping?

Comment: I've edited the question, provided tables for the entities with full property to column mappings

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by introducing a "Dummy" Relationship Class as Entity which I then use as join in the JPA Query to access the property for which I am using the `@OrderColumn`

Here a high level example based on your code. I have it not tested, however it might help you and others.

Assuming you have `@OrderColumn("sort_order")` class annotation for your "countries" member which then is located in the Join Table "category_2_country"

```
public class Category implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_2_country",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c2c_category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c2c_country_id"))
    @OrderColumn("sort_order")  
    private Set<Country> countries;
}

// Dummy entity relationship class which represents a single row in your JoinTable
@Entity
@Table(name = "category_2_country")
public class Category2Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "c2c_category_id ", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer categoryId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "c2c_country_id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer countryId;

    @Column(name = "sort_order", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Integer sortOrder;

}
```

With that you can then create JPA Query with `INNER JOIN` where you then can user the "sortOrder" property. This gives the advantage not to use native Query.

```
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Category ct"
            + "INNER JOIN Category2Counry cc ON cc.categoryId = ct.id 
            + "INNER JOIN Country c ON cc.countryId = c.id "
            + "WHERE ct.id = :id "
            + "ORDER BY cc.sortOrder ASC")
    List<Country> findCountriesByCategorySorted(@Param("id") Integer id);
}
```

Hope this helps.