# Order resulting collection of JPA query by @OrderColumn of join table

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, sql-order-by, micronaut, micronaut-data

I have the following entities within my Micronaut 3.0.3 application.

```java
public class Game extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @ToString.Exclude
  @OrderColumn(name = "sort_index")
  private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}

public abstract class Question extends BaseEntity {
... // omitted
}
```

The order column works well when I'm accessing the questions through the level, so that hibernate can handle the ordering for me:

```java
// (pseudo) ordered correctly:
gameRepository.findById(id).getQuestions();
```

But I want to use the question repository directly, like this:

```java
  @Query(
  """
      select q from Question q, Game g
      where g.id = :game
      and q in elements(g.questions)

----> order by sort_index of game_questions table
  """)
  Collection<Question> findAllByGame(UUID game);
```

Need help with the ordering part of the questions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make the sort column available as mapped property Or by using Native Queries

In case you have no intermediate JoinTable and your "Question" has a foreign key for your "Game" Entity then it is very simple, you can add the order column as property in your "Question" entity.

```
public abstract class Question extends BaseEntity {

   ...
    @Column(name = "sort_index ", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Getter
    private Integer sortIndex;

}
```

A query in your Repository could then look like this

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Integer>,

    @Query("SELECT q FROM Game g "
            + "JOIN g.questions AS q "
            + "WHERE g.name = :name "
            + "ORDER BY q.sortIndex ASC")
    List<Question> findQuestionsByGameNameSorted(@Param("name") String name);
```

In case your data model is more complex and you have an intermediate `@JoinTable` i.e. "game_questions", then I solved this by introducing a "Dummy" Relationship Class as Entity which I then use as join in the JPA Query to access the sort property for which I am using the `@OrderColumn`

Here a high level example:

[JPA Order by column in many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936247/jpa-order-by-column-in-many-to-many-relationship/78095938#78095938)

Hope this helps.