# How to set the @Id of the intermediate table of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

The intermediate table of a many-to-many relationship contains extra column , struct_code :

```
create table acteur_saisie_indicateur 
(
   indi_code            number(15)           not null,
   struct_code          varchar2(15)         not null,
   user_code            number(10)           not null,
   constraint pk_acteur_saisie_indicateur primary key (indi_code,struct_code,user_code)
);
```

My problem is about the @Id annotation for the entity corresponding to it : on which attributes should it be set ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns/5127262