# Hibernate 5 mapping another table column with annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sql-server-2012, hibernate-5.x

I have this tables in SQL

```
-TABLE CATEGORY-
ID_CATEGORY, NAME

-TABLE CATEGORY_EVENTS-
ID_CATEGORY, ID_EVENT, COLUMNIWANT

-TABLE EVENTS-
ID_EVENT, NAME
```

Then I have my entitys in java like this

***Category.java***:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_CATEGORY")
private long idCategory;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@IDONTKNOW
private int COLUMNIWANT
```

***Event.java***:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_EVENT")
private long idEvent;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "CATEGORY_EVENTS", 
         joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_EVENT") }, 
         inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CATEGORY") })
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
```

The COLUMNIWANT need to be inside each category in  categories list inside events but it may not be in a normal category not associated to an event.

So my question is, how should I do the Hibernate mapping with the COLUMNIWANT property in categories.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you want COLUMNIWANT to be used but it should not save in Database while save/Update if so you can annotate it with @Transient

Comment: It's a classic structure: attributes in the link table. Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns