# JPA many-to-many with additional atribute without use additional class

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, orm, spring-data-jpa

I had two class join with many to many relationship.

[image]

I use below code to do that

this is Member.class

```
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "member")
    public class Member implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;
        
        @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "event_info_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true) })
        private Set<EventInfo> eventInfo= new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is Eventinfo.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_info")
@Data
public class EventInfo implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "event_name")
    private String eventName;
    
    @Column(name = "event_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date eventDate;
    
    @Column(name = "event_description")
    private String eventDescription;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "eventInfo")
    private Set<EventPic> eventPicSet;
    
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Event event;
    
}
```

Now I need to add more additional attribute to associate table. Is there any way to do that without using additional entity class.

> I need only way that solve using this member.class and event_info.class
>
> if there is no way why is that?

additional attribute is date

[image]

Comment: please tell us where in your JAVA model is this "additional attribute"

Comment: @DN1 I added new image. it contain member_event_info associate table. can I add this attribute without developing member_event_info.class

Comment: I asked for the JAVA model. JPA persists what is in your JAVA CLASSES. If this attribute is not in your classes where do you expect it to magic the information from?!!

Comment: @DN  I ask not magic. If it can or cant ? is there any wrong please guide me

Comment: So you have no attribute then? So the answer is NO.

Comment: @Dn1 
1 -can you understand this question. 1st image show the many-to-many relationship. that two java class provide solution for that.

2- now i add new attribute to associate entity call data. then i can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns this link to solve that. but he go to additional class. is a way that solve without additional class

Comment: We've already seen that you dont want to have an attribute in your java model, so no you cannot do that without an intermediate class (that has the attribute). So No. No. No. No.

Comment: You can use `@AssociationOverrides` but the code gets very cluttered and hard to understand and manage. Check an example [here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/).